# Editing comand prompt

Tags: linux, bash

I've changed shell prompt (modifying `PS1` variable) for `tty1`. Is there a way to change the modified prompt for `tty1` from `tty2` (after switching to tty2 by `Alt+F2`)?

Comment: You don't change "prompt for `tty1`". You change `PS1` variable within some `bash` process. So the question is: is there a way to change a shell variable from the outside of the shell itself? (like from another shell).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski that's a harder question ;-) I'd assume it already exists somewhere. Anyway, before I switch to a different tty in Debian/antiX/MX, there's no bash running there, so just changing the login/rc files to a new prompt would be good enough for starting a new tty. I don't think `tset` resets *everything*, but just `. .bashrc` should work too

Answer (score 0):

Configure `.profile`, or whatever your shell uses, to set `PS1` differently depending on the output of the command `tty`.

That doesn't *change* the prompt when switching virtual terminals, but sets it up when you start the shell (which is a much better way of doing it).